# A link doesn't work. Is it possible that Jquery 'toggle()' method causes this?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div>                                           
  <h3 class="ft-default bold inline-block">Callback</h3>                                            
     <ul class="Browsingtree02">
     <li><a href="/description.html">LoadCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>ChangeCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>beforeJobCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>afterJobCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>afterListCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>afterReadCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>tdClickCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>trClickCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>BlurCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>parentSetDefault</a></li>
     <li><a>setValueCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>keyDownCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>afterNewCallBack</a></li>
     <li><a>afterDeleteCallBack</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

===============================================================================

As above, you can see the first element 'a' with 'href' attribute.
Normally, it works fine, there's no reason for it not to work, 
because it's a simple 'a' tag with href attribute.

But it gets a problem when I put toggle function on the element.

===============================================================================

```
$('#Left .Browsingtree02 li a').toggle(function() {
    $(this).addClass('Selected');   
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.Browsingtree03').show(200);
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.Browsingtree03').hide(200);
    $(this).removeClass('Selected');
});
```

===============================================================================

If this code doesn't exist, the first 'a' with the attribute works just fine !!

But Browser can't get the link and doesn't move to the linked page at all...

Please help me out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/JTaA4/ --- as you could see - it's not a problem

Comment: @zerkms it works there because #Left does not exist so it doesn't trigger the function

Comment: @dystroy: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @Anton: so? It works. If something else important wasn't provided - it's not my issue.

Comment: I didn't paste an ancestor of the ul element, a div with id "Left". So forget about it. the problem is that I can't get the link on the first a element.... toggle function works just fine as well.

Comment: Toggle function works okay just as I expected, it attached 'Selected' class to an clicked element, and show the lower level tree in a list.

Comment: But what I can't get it is that the simple 'a link' is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons, jQuery's toggle always prevents the default action. See [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) :

```
// Make sure that clicks stop
event.preventDefault();
```

So I suggest to not use the toggle function but simply to do this :

```
$('#Left .Browsingtree02 li a').click(function(){
    var nbclicks = $(this).data('nbc')||0;
    $(this).data('nbc', ++nbclicks);
    if (nbclicks%2) {
        $(this).addClass('Selected');   
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.Browsingtree03').show(200);
    } else { 
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.Browsingtree03').hide(200);
        $(this).removeClass('Selected');
    }
});​
```